# how to store multiple value in column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I am creating job post application. In my first table the columns are This is my master table

```
ID
Position
jobDescription
minExp
maxExp
LastDate
InterviewDate
Project
HiringManager
interviewer
Primaryskills
SecondorySkills
```

and second table contains the primary skills PrimarySkill table

```
ID
PrimarySkills
```

third Table contains the secondory skills

```
ID
SecondarySkills
```

fourth Table contains the Interviewer

```
ID
Interviewer
```

the problem is that if a person have multiple skills and multiple interviewer for a job, Then how can insert the value from primary skill table, secondory skill table and interviewer table in Master table. i do not want to store value in comma separated

Comment: It sounds like you don't understand the relational model at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to store multiple values in a single column in the jobs table; this calls for what is known as a junction or many-to-many table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Jobs
(
  JobID             INT PRIMARY KEY,
  JobTitle          VARCHAR(255),
  JobDescription    NVARCHAR(4000),
  MinimumExperience TINYINT,
  MaximumExperience TINYINT,
  LastDate          DATETIME, -- what is this? Needs a better name I think
  InterviewDate     DATETIME, -- is this really a property of the job?
  ProjectID         INT, -- foreign key references dbo.Projects?
  HiringManagerID   INT, -- foreign key references Employees table?
  InterviewerID     INT  -- foreign key references something?
);
```

(Assuming there is only one interviewer. If there are multiple, consider a many-to-many table.)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Skills
(
  SkillID SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
  SkillName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.JobSkills
(
  JobID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Jobs(JobID),
  SkillID SMALLINT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Skills(SkillID),
  IsPrimary BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 3 Columns (Primary Skills, Secondary Skills and Interviewer) should be removed from Master Table.
2. New Table should be created (X Table).
3. In this X Table Map the Id's of all the 4 table (i.e. Master Table,
   PrimarySkill Table, SecondarySkill Table and Interviewer Table) should be entered and mapped.

Also it would be good benefit while retrieving the data through Select Query.

Comment: how can i map, if person have multiple skills. in the x table

Comment: In X Table - 4 columns having different IDs coming from 4 tables. If ID-1 from Master Table - 1 Primary Skill other column-row will be NULL, 3 Secondary Skill others will be NULL and 4 interviewer ids mapped with specific Primary / Secondary skill then it should be mapped likewise